# How to center nodes without using centering force?

Tags: d3.js, centering, force-layout

I have a force layout graph where user adds nodes dynamically. How can i center all my nodes with a bit distance between, and make them move independently and not around the center.

I have tried removing the `d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2)` which makes nodes move independently but then it possitions all nodes at (0, 0).

```
simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(0))
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

I want all the nodes to be centered and move independently.

EDIT:

I tried setting `cx` and `cy` values but that did not work either.

```
  const nodeEnter = nodeElements
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 20)
    .attr('fill', 'orange')
    .attr('cx', (d, i) => {
      return (width / 2) + i * 10;
    })
    .attr('cy', (d, i) => {
      return (height / 2) + i * 10;
    })
    .call(dragDrop(simulation))
    .on('click', ({ id }) => handleClick(id));
```

Comment: why can't you use both forces? what do you mean by independently?

Comment: @thedude when forceCenter is present, all the nodes are placed around (width / 2, height / 2). If i move 1 node then all other nodes move relatively in order to keep the center of mass at the same spot. I don't want that behavior. I want all nodes to be placed at center. But when i move 1 node the rest of the nodes should stay where they are.

Answer (score 2):

Given what you said in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377221/how-to-center-nodes-without-using-centering-force#comment99355736_56377221)...

> If i move 1 node then all other nodes move relatively in order to keep the center of mass at the same spot.

... you already know that `forceCenter` is the wrong tool for the task, since it will keep the centre of mass.

Therefore, just replace it for `forceX` and `forceY`:

```
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force('centerX', d3.forceX(width / 2))
    .force('centerY', d3.forceY(height / 2));
```

Since you didn't provide enough code here is a general demo:

```css
svg {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="300"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const svg = d3.select('svg');

  const width = svg.attr('width');
  const height = svg.attr('height');

  const data = d3.range(50).map(() => ({}));

  const node = svg.selectAll()
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .attr('fill', 'teal')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on('start', dragstarted)
      .on('drag', dragged)
      .on('end', dragended));

  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-15))
    .force('centerX', d3.forceX(width / 2))
    .force('centerY', d3.forceY(height / 2));

  simulation
    .nodes(data)
    .on('tick', ticked);

  function ticked() {
    node.attr('cx', d => d.x)
      .attr('cy', d => d.y);
  }

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried this as well, but this makes the nodes on drag end to return to center. I, however, want them to stay on the place where i left them.

Comment: Is the most optimal way to do that to add to dragended `d.fx = d3.event.x;` and `d.fy = d3.event.y;` ?

Comment: As i figured out that is not the most optimal way. My code includes `.force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(20))` which don't allow nodes to overlap. If however i drag a node and leave it one place then it can be everlaped with other nodes.

Comment: *"Yes, i have tried this as well"*... so, put that in the question. Regarding your other comments, those are different issues. Please keep it just one issue per question.